# Partial sums of harmonic series

Tags: math

Formula:

[image]

I was told by my math teacher that it is impossible to calculate from the formula above n that is neccesary for sum to exceed 40 ( sum > 40), and know the sum in 50 decimals precision.

(in short: First n that is neccesary for sum > 40, and what would that sum be in 50 decimals precision)

I tryed writing c++ program for this, but realized after tno of optimizations that it would take just way too long.

Comment: This is a great learning exercise. You have two general approaches. One is to try to speed up the looping of a simple summation so that it is workable for n on the order off 10^17. The other is to exploit some identities which change the summation into some other calculation. In either case, you must consider what it takes to prove that your calculation is correct to the specified 50 digits. Good luck and keep up the good work.

Answer (score 3):

H_n is bounded below by ln n + gamma where gamma is the Euler-Mascheroni constant (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). So you can start by finding n such that \ln n + gamma = 40.  Solving, you get ln n = 40 - gamma, n = e^(40-gamma), which is quite straightforward to calculate. Once you know the ballpark, you can use a binary search and more accurate over and under estimates for H_n (see the asymptotic expansion at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation; there are many references that can provide more detail).

Answer (score 0):

Why would that be impossible? It's

```
40.00000000000000000202186036912232961108532260403356
```

Steps to get there:

1. [Ask Wolfram Alpha for the number `n` where the sum equals 40](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2Fj%2C+j%3D1+to+n+%3D+40).
2. You'll get something around `1.32159290357566702732792368 10^17`. Pick the next higher integer.
3. [Compute the sum for n = 132159290357566703](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2Fj%2C+j%3D1+to+132159290357566703).
4. Click on "More digits" until satisfied.

Comment: You also need to calculate the sum for n = 132159290357566702 to show that it is less than 40.

Comment: The issue is, I need to calculate sum for n = 1.32(and another 48 digits) *10^17, and wolfram cant do that